# Removing lines with non-English characters using Perl

Tags: perl, non-english

Given this data

```
TRMMJJH12903CF8B69<SEP>SOKSZAQ12AC9070DC0<SEP>Alexandre Da Costa<SEP>Violin Concerto No.1 in G minor_ Op.26 - III. Allegro energico

TRMMOWW128F1465642<SEP>SOGELZG12A6D4F865F<SEP>Yann Tiersen<SEP>La Valse D'Amélie (Version Orchestre)
```

I have to weed out all of the things before the song title, which I have done successfully.

Then I must remove everything after a `+`, `(`, `{`, `[`, etc. which I have done successfully.

The part I am stuck on is, if the line has a non-English character like the Yann Tiersen song, then I must eliminate it entirely.

I have tried looking in the docs to figure out how to use `\w` and `\s` but I cannot understand how to put it into code and use it.

Here is my code:

```
@songs = map { chomp; (split /<SEP>/)[3] } @data;
for (my $i = 0 ; $i < @songs . length ; $i++) {

  $title = @songs[$i];
  $title =~ s/feat..*//s;
  $title =~ s/\(.*//s;
  $title =~ s/\[.*//s;
  $title =~ s/\{.*//s;
  $title =~ s/\/.*//s;
  $title =~ s/\\.*//s;
  $title =~ s/\+.*//s;
  $title =~ s/\=.*//s;
  $title =~ s/\*.*//s;
  $title =~ s/\".*//s;
  $title =~ s/\:.*//s;
  $title =~ s/\-.*//s;
  $title =~ s/\'.*//s;
  $title =~ s/\_.*//s;
  $title =~ s/\?.*//s;
  $title =~ s/\..*//s;
  $title =~ s/\!.*//s;
  $title =~ s/\;.*//s;
  $title =~ s/\&.*//s;
  $title =~ s/\$.*//s;
  $title =~ s/\%.*//s;
  $title =~ s/\#.*//s;
  $title =~ s/\|.*//s;
  $title =~ s/\@.*//s;
  $title =~ s/\.*//s;
  $title =~ s/\!.*//s;
  $title =~ s/\¿.*//s;
  $title =~ s/\¡.*//s;
  $title !~ s/[^[:ascii:]]//g;
  $title = lc($title);

  print $title, $i, "\n";

}
```

The output looks like this:

```
violin concerto no
la valse d
```

The second line should not be there.

Comment: That is an amazingly inefficient way of going about things! Are you just trying to isolate the song name from the above example?

Comment: Specifically what are you trying achieve?

Comment: What's the "second line"?

Comment: i am trying to remove the line totally if it has a non english character.  I know it is inefficent this was just the first thing I have tried and i just kept adding on.  The "second line" is the la valse d.  That line should be completely gone

Comment: The Perl code that you show deletes a lot of *punctuation*. Is that right? You say you want to "remove a line totally if it has a non-English character". That means nothing would survive from your example data, because the first line contains a full-stop and the second has an apostrophe. Also, is there *really* a blank line between the text records? You must show *exactly* what you are dealing with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;   

my @data = ('TRMMJJH12903CF8B69<SEP>SOKSZAQ12AC9070DC0<SEP>Alexandre Da Costa<SEP>Violin Concerto No.1 in G minor_ Op.26 - III. Allegro energico', 'TRMMOWW128F1465642<SEP>SOGELZG12A6D4F865F<SEP>Yann Tiersen<SEP>La Valse D\'Amélie');

foreach (@data){
    my @split = split(/<SEP>/);
    print "$split[3]\n" unless /[^[:ascii:]]/;
}
```

Prints:

```
Violin Concerto No.1 in G minor_ Op.26 - III. Allegro energico
```